# Returning data from asyncronous calls between unity and the web browser

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous

I'm working on a project where we're using unity to build a webgl enabled application for use in a browser.

Because of some issues surrounding authentication and cookies we're having to use a `.jslib` plugin to map some of the unity calls to javascript calls in the website's code.

The code mapping between the two applications is working fine, but I'm running into a async issue in one of the plugin functions

I'm working on the following plugin code map:

```
  AuthenticatedGet: function (uri) {
    var uriString = Pointer_stringify(uri)

    var result = authenticatedGetRequest(uriString)

    var buffer = _malloc(lengthBytesUTF8(result) + 1)
    writeStringToMemory(result, buffer)

    return buffer
  },
```

Which calls the following function in the website codebase:

```
function authenticatedGetRequest(uri) {
  let endpoint = wpApiSettings.root + uri

  $.ajax({
    url: endpoint,
    method: "GET",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", wpApiSettings.nonce)
    },
    data: {},
  })
    .done((response) => {
      // ? do we need to stringify?
      return JSON.stringify(response)
    })
    .fail((error) => {
      console.error(error)
      return error
    })
}
```

The problem comes in the plugin's call to `authenticatedGetRequest`. Since that function contains a promise I need to wait for the async call to finish.

I tried rewriting the code to return and handle the promise:

Plugin code:

```
AuthenticatedGet: function (uri) {
    var uriString = Pointer_stringify(uri)

    var result = authenticatedGetRequest(uriString).then((response) => {
      var buffer = _malloc(lengthBytesUTF8(result) + 1)
      writeStringToMemory(result, buffer)

      return buffer
    })
  },
```

Website code:

```
function authenticatedGetRequest(uri) {
  let endpoint = wpApiSettings.root + uri

  return $.ajax({
    url: endpoint,
    method: "GET",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", wpApiSettings.nonce)
    },
    data: {},
  })
    .done((response) => {
      // ? do we need to stringify?
      return JSON.stringify(response)
    })
    .fail((error) => {
      console.error(error)
      return error
    })
}
```

But doing this causes a build error on the unity side:

[image: unity build error]

I should note that if I fake out the response on the website side by immediately returning with a string (removing the async nature of the call), everything works fine.

I'm pretty new to unity and c# in general so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use `async`/`await` in your plugin code?

Comment: @JohanP yeah, I tried that too and it gives the same build error.

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @cmadh from what I could tell it wasn't possible. I ended up taking a step back and rethinking our problem. The whole reason the devs who originally wrote the mapping was because we needed the wordpress nonce to authenticate web calls so they sent all of the web calls through the wordpress js. The thing is, the nonce is available globally as soon as the browser loads the js, so instead of shoving requests through javascript, I just used the jslib to grab the nonce from the global javascript variable and stored it in c#, then included it in the headers for native web requests in unity's c#.

Comment: @cmadh I don't work for that company anymore, so I can't pull the code snippet to show you exactly, but I basically used the jslib to return the wordpress nonce, stored it in a private property for a `WebUtilities` signleton class I wrote, and then used the `WWWForm` c# object to create web forms and added the nonce to the headers for the request. From there it was just like doing regular html form requests directly from unity/c# to wordpress/php, no javascript layer needed.